# PL/SQL Cursor just check if value is greater than a value

Tags: plsql

I want
to make a procedure check if exist `empno` from table `employees`
with `emno` greater than `100`. If exist at least one, i want
to exit from the loop.

How can I modify the following code ?
Is it problem I don;t use %NOTFOUND , %ROWCOUNT ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure check_value
IS

cursor c1 is 
    select *
    from employess;
    
c1_values c1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

   open c1;
   fetch c1 into c1_values;
   loop
        if c1_values.EMPNO > 100 then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Found row with empno > 100');
        end if;
   end loop;
   close c1;

END;
```

Comment: Can you provide more details of a problem? In this formulation you need just execute single sql query (without PL/SQL) in SQL*Plus as `select * from emp where empno > 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to check if you have a record which has empno over 100 you can use `EXISTS` statement e.g.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    1
                FROM
                    employees
                WHERE
                    empno > 100
            ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS empno_exists
    FROM
        dual;

    ln_empno_exists     PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 INTO ln_empno_exists;
    CLOSE c1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Empno over 100 exists: '||CASE WHEN ln_empno_exists = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END);

END;
/
```

EDIT: If you want to fetch the rows with some conditions, you simply need to adjust your `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` statement. Here you have an example with some ways to iterate through the records fetched:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
        emp.*
    FROM
        employees emp
    WHERE
        empno > 100
    ;

    lr_c1_rec       c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    -- Using FOR loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START: Printing employees records where empno > 100');
    FOR rec IN c1
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('empno = '||rec.empno);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END: Printing employees records where empno > 100');



    -- Using a LOOP with EXIT clause
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START: Printing employees records where empno > 100');
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO lr_c1_rec;
        -- exit the loop when your cursor doesn't have any more records to be returned
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('empno = '||lr_c1_rec.empno);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END: Printing employees records where empno > 100');

    -- Using WHILE loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START: Printing employees records where empno > 100');
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 INTO lr_c1_rec;
    -- As long as cursor returns any values, iterate through the records returned
    WHILE c1%FOUND
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('empno = '||lr_c1_rec.empno);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END: Printing employees records where empno > 100');
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want and other columns from these row ie ename (later in the procedure).
For this reason I thought a loop is better.
But I don't know how can I do the loop with exit when statement printing the also the message.

Comment: Hey. Gave you a little example of fetching the desired rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `EXIT` statement after you've found your value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure check_value IS
  cursor c1 is 
    select *
    from employess;

  c1_values c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   open c1;

   loop
     fetch c1 into c1_values;
     IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN EXIT;

     if c1_values.EMPNO > 100 then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Found row with empno > 100');
       EXIT;
     end if;
   end loop;

   -- The EXIT statement will drop you out of the loop and leave you here

   close c1;
END;
```

Note that I moved the `fetch` inside the loop and added a %NOTFOUND check. Without the %NOTFOUND the code would never know the cursor was out of data and would probably go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Why to define cursor and then open and fetch when it can be done by just 
>   SQL But if it is required so then use FOR loop and EXIT condition
>   as mentioned
>
> below. Hope it helps

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_value
IS
BEGIN
  FOR I IN
  (SELECT * FROM employess
  )
  LOOP
    IF I.EMPNO > 5 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Found row with empno > 100');
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```